# Converting a VMDK file to VHD

Tags: azure, vhd, vmdk

I am having trouble with converting a vmdk file to a vhd file.

Is it possible to convert a vmdk file without running it in a VM. So it will just convert and create the same file but in VHD format?

The size of the vmdk file is 400GB and I am wanting to eventually upload it into Azure

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

[Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-my/download/details.aspx?id=42497). It will even upload it to Azure for you.

Comment: I am trying to use this and I am up to "Source" section but I don't have a VM to connect to, I just have the vmdk file. Is is possible to convert the file without connecting to a VM. I have tried converting it how @blaughw said and I get this error; "No suitable drive was found at path (file\path\name.vmdk). Could this be happening because it is located on an External HDD??

Comment: See the answer from blaughw below, refer to the answer on superuser: http://superuser.com/a/515985/391940

Comment: Thankyou everyone. I am currently using another program called 'WinImage' and if that doesn't work then I'll be back

Answer (score 0):

Blerg, this is a duplicate, but the dupe was migrated to SuperUser FROM SF.se.

https://superuser.com/a/515985/391940

See Mark Henderson's answer, that's the gist of it.

Comment: Actually it came from SO, and that's because SO cannot migrate to SF any more. This is probably a case where it should have come here.